# What is the correct effective sample size (ESS) calculation?

Tags: r, variance, sample-size, autocorrelation, markov-chain-montecarlo

I wish to compute the effective sample size (ESS) for a posterior sample of size $M$.  I have looked at several documentations (e.g. [WinBUGS](https://people.orie.cornell.edu/davidr/or678/handouts/winBUGS.pdf) p11; [Stan](https://mc-stan.org/docs/2_20/reference-manual/effective-sample-size-section.html) sec 15.4) and several other Stack Exchange questions (e.g. [this](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/66369/definition-of-autocorrelation-time-for-effective-sample-size) and [this](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/296059/effective-sample-size-greater-than-actual-sample-size/315874)). There seems to be several variations of definitions of variance (what correction to use in denominator), autocorrelation, and ESS formulas.  I have tried many variations, but none of them match the results from `effectiveSize()`.  At the 'top-level', the first 2 sources concur that the formula for ESS is:

$$ESS=\frac{M}{1+2\sum_{k=1}\rho_k}$$

although variants exist, such as [here](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/66369/definition-of-autocorrelation-time-for-effective-sample-size), suggesting it should be $|\rho|$, and [here](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/296059/effective-sample-size-greater-than-actual-sample-size/315874), suggesting a completely different variant:

$$ESS=M\frac{\lambda^2}{\sigma^2}, ~~~\text{ where } \sigma^2 = \lambda^2 + 2\sum_{k=1}\rho_k \text{ and } \lambda^2 = \text{var}(x)$$

where $x$ is a vector representing an estimate of a parameter at each MCMC iteration.  Then there is the issue of how the autocorrelation, $\rho$, is calculated. [This](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/66369/definition-of-autocorrelation-time-for-effective-sample-size) suggests:

$$\rho_k = \frac{\text{cov}[x_t, x_{t+k}]}{\text{var}[x_t]}$$

where $\text{var}[x_t]$ could have a denominator of $M$ or $M-1$.  But most sources just describe $\rho$ without giving an explicit formula, e.g. "...$\rho_k$ is the lag $k$ autocorrelation for one parameter..." [link](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/66369/definition-of-autocorrelation-time-for-effective-sample-size).

I'm not even confident about the expressions for $x_t$ and $x_{t+k}$.  My understanding is

$$x_t = \{x_1,x_2,\ldots,x_{M-k}\}$$
$$x_{t+k} = \{x_{k+1},x_{k+2},\ldots,x_M\}$$

I can compute the ESS in R using the `coda` package easily enough:

```
coda::effectiveSize(x)
```

But I want to understand how this is computed.

So what is the correct definition of the ESS?

---

For clarity, I have provided R code (updated for new variant) which attempts to demonstrate the lack of agreement.

Here is a user-defined R function which computes several variations of `rho` ($\rho$) and the ESS formula:

```
get.ESS <- function(x, autocor = 1, ESS = 1){
    M <- length(x)
    # Re-centre at zero
    x <- x - mean(x)
    # Autocorrelations
    rho <- rep(NA, M-2)
    for(lag in 0:(M-2)){
        # Split time-series in two, separated by 'lag'
        theta.1 <- x[1:(M-lag)]
        theta.2 <- x[(1+lag):M]
        # Autocorrelation
        if(autocor %in% c(1, 4)){
            rho[lag + 1] <- cor(theta.2, theta.1)
        }else if(autocor == 2){
            rho[lag + 1] <- mean(theta.1 * theta.2) / var(x)
        }else if(autocor == 5){
            rho[lag + 1] <- cov(theta.2, theta.1)
        }
    }
    if(autocor == 3){
        rho <- stats::acf(x = x, lag.max = M-2, plot = FALSE)$acf
    }else if(autocor == 4){
        # 'Relative' autocorrelation
        rho <- rho * (M - 0:(M-2)) / M
    }

    # Effective sample size
    if(ESS == 1){
        E <- M / (1 + 2 * sum(rho))
    }else if(ESS == 2){
        E <- M / (1 + 2 * sum(abs(rho))) 
    }else if(ESS == 3){     # To be used with autocor = 5
        lambda.sq <- M * var(x)
        sigma.sq <- lambda.sq + 2 * sum(rho)
        E <- M * lambda.sq / sigma.sq
    }
    return(E)
}
```

The arguments `autocor` and `ESS` set the variation to be computed.  Results:

```
M <- 300    # Number of MCMC iterations
set.seed(1)
x <- rnorm(M, 0, 1)

get.ESS(x, 1, 1)        # -178.352
get.ESS(x, 2, 1)        # 153.4736
get.ESS(x, 3, 1)        # 150.1211
get.ESS(x, 4, 1)        # 149.9286
get.ESS(x, 5, 1)        # 367.5048

get.ESS(x, 1, 2)        # 5.553791
get.ESS(x, 2, 2)        # 6.272066
get.ESS(x, 3, 2)        # 14.85799
get.ESS(x, 4, 2)        # 14.65066
get.ESS(x, 5, 2)        # 6.524995

# Compare with:
coda::effectiveSize(x)          # 300 = M
```

As you can see, these aren't even *close* to being correct.  The help file on `effectiveSize` wasn't very helpful on how they compute it.

So what is the correct effective sample size (ESS) calculation (at least that which is used by `effectiveSize`)?

---

Update:

Using the variant suggested [here](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/296059/effective-sample-size-greater-than-actual-sample-size/315874), i.e. $ESS=M\frac{\lambda^2}{\sigma^2}$:

```
get.ESS(x, 1, 3)        # 300.0289
get.ESS(x, 2, 3)        # 299.9897
get.ESS(x, 3, 3)        # 299.9893
get.ESS(x, 4, 3)        # 299.9892
get.ESS(x, 5, 3)        # 300.1979   - the actual definition proposed
```

The results *seem* correct, regardless of the variant of $\rho$ (which is strange).  Using a highly correlated sample for $x$ instead of white noise shows similar values (300 or larger), which is clearly wrong - it should reduce as correlation increases.  So the question still stands.

Comment: What do you mean by "correct"?

Comment: I think the last sentence already clarifies this? Given the sample is white noise, the ESS should be as large as the *actual* sample size, i.e. 300.

Comment: Just noticed that the second equation appears messed up if you're viewing this in Chrome, but it appears just fine in Firefox. This is not something I can fix :S

Answer (score 16, accepted):

After further research, I've made some useful discoveries.  The answer appears to be anything but straightforward.  Let me start by answering my second question above: "What is the correct effective sample size (ESS) calculation (at least that which is used by `effectiveSize`)?"

The answer is that the `effectiveSize` function from the R `coda` package uses the second definition I described in the question, namely

$$ESS = M \frac{\lambda^2}{\sigma^2}$$

where $\lambda^2 = \text{var}(x)$ is the sample variance as defined above, but $\sigma^2$ is defined as an estimate of the spectral density at frequency zero.  (`effectiveSize` uses the function `spectrum0.ar` to do this, also from the `coda` package.)  More generally, $\sigma^2$ is an estimate of the variance in the Central Limit Theorem.

I wish I understood what "the spectral density at frequency zero" meant so I could elaborate, but hopefully this is a useful starting point for anyone who wishes to a) understand the calculation behind `coda::effectiveSize` or b) wishes to program a user-defined function for computing sample size.

---

Now to answer my first question: "What is the correct definition of the ESS?"

As far as I can tell, **there isn't one correct definition**.  What tipped me off was [a paper](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1403.5536v1.pdf) which mentioned two R packages for calculating the ESS.  After trying both on toy examples, I was still getting drastically different results.  I'm not sure what definition of ESS is being used in the second package (`mcmcse::ess`), but it demonstrates multiple definitions do exist.  On that note, here is a concise list of definitions that I've found so far. (Disclaimer: *I cannot vouch for their correctness*.)

Note that they all take the general form:

$$
ESS_{\text{i}} = \frac{M}{\tau_i}
$$
where $M$ is the un-adjusted sample size (i.e. length of the vector $x$), and subscript $i$ denotes the specific definition.  Hence I will focus on the definitions of $\tau_i$.  In no particular order:

$$
\tau_1 = 1 + 2\sum_{l=1}^\infty \rho(l)
$$

where $\rho(l)$ is the sample autocorrelation at lag $l$.

Sources: https://www.johndcook.com/blog/2017/06/27/effective-sample-size-for-mcmc/, https://mc-stan.org/docs/2_20/reference-manual/effective-sample-size-section.html, https://people.orie.cornell.edu/davidr/or678/handouts/winBUGS.pdf, https://arxiv.org/pdf/1403.5536v1.pdf

$$
\tau_2 = \frac{1+\rho(1)}{1-\rho(1)}
$$

Source: https://imedea.uib-csic.es/master/cambioglobal/Modulo_V_cod101615/Theory/TSA_theory_part1.pdf

\begin{align*}
\tau_3 = & \frac{1}{M}\sum_{k,l=1}^M \text{cov}(x_k, x_l) \\
      = &1 + 2 \left( \frac{M-1}{M}\rho_1 + \frac{M-2}{M}\rho_2 + \cdots + \frac{1}{M}\rho_{M-1}\right)
\end{align*}

(Note this is similar to $\tau_1$, but seems to use covariance rather than autocorrelation.  Also, it seems $x_k$ and $x_l$ are scalars rather than vectors, which makes no sense to me.)

Source: [Definition of autocorrelation time (for effective sample size)](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/66369/definition-of-autocorrelation-time-for-effective-sample-size)

$$
\tau_4 = \frac{\sigma^2}{\lambda^2}
$$

where $\lambda^2 = \text{var}(x)$ and $\sigma^2 = \lambda^2 + 2\sum_{l=1}\rho(l)$.

Sources: https://arxiv.org/pdf/1403.5536v1.pdf, [Effective Sample Size greater than Actual Sample Size](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/296059/effective-sample-size-greater-than-actual-sample-size/315874), https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/mcmcse/mcmcse.pdf

$$
\tau_5 = \frac{\sigma^2}{\lambda^2}
$$

where $\lambda^2 = \text{var}(x)$ and $\sigma^2$ is an estimate of the spectral density at frequency zero (the `coda::effectiveSize` definition above).

Note that the [Stan Reference Manual](https://mc-stan.org/docs/2_20/reference-manual/effective-sample-size-section.html) provides an extension to $ESS_1$ for multiple MCMC chains.